# What's the code if the checkbox is checked on the userform and then colored on the database sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I created a userform which has a checkbox. if I check the 'thickness' section, then on the database sheet the 'thickness' column is also colored red. what is the code guys? cause if i use this code it doesn't work in my excel

```
If CBThickness.Value = True Then
Sheets("Database Adjustment").Range("I").Interior.Color = vbRed
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Range("I")` throws an error.  `.Range("I:I")` refers to all the cells in column I as does `Columns("I")`.

> ```
> Sheets("Database Adjustment").Range("I:I").Interior.Color = vbRed
> ```

Or

> ```
> Sheets("Database Adjustment").Columns("I").Interior.Color = vbRed
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how if one column only? because i use your code, it makes all column colored

Comment: @ElviraAmanda What cell do you want colored?  You should watch this tutorial [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&t=75s)

Comment: If i want to use 'offset'. How combining that?

Comment: @ElviraAmanda You need to provide a starting row.  a.k.a. `.Range("I1").Offset()`